# Excel Bulk Save Images through Powerpoint, .Shapes.SaveAs not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I need to bulk same images embedded in Excel to original resolution. I found this code on internet, but it's not working and needs modification.

1. It gives an error at **.Shapes.SaveAs**
2. The images are embedded in cell with 9% of original size. This code saves 9% of original size. I need the original size saved.

```
Sub SaveImages()
    'the location to save all the images
    Const destFolder = "C:\Users\user\Documents\test4\"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2PASTE")

    Dim ppt As Object, ps As Variant, slide As Variant

    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
    Set ps = ppt.presentations.Add
    Set slide = ps.slides.Add(1, 1)

    Dim shp As Shape, shpName
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        shpName = shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1) & ".png"
        shp.Copy
        With slide
            .Shapes.Paste
            'This is the point where the code breaks, when I try to save
            .Shapes.SaveAs Filename:=destFolder & shpName
            .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Delete
        End With
    Next shp

    With ps
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
    ppt.Quit
    Set ppt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Let me get this right. You copied and pasted some VBA, it doesn't work, and you want us to fix it for you? First place to start is to understand what the code is doing, by checking out VBA Docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with your code and got it to work on my end. I think the issue is that you are not telling it which picture to save, you just have

```
Shapes.SaveAs
```

as opposed to, say,

```
Shapes(1).SaveAs
```

However, via Google I found a different picture saving syntax... here's my code:

```
Sub SaveImages()
    'Save Images Here
    Const destFolder = " -- "
    'This Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2PASTE")
    
    Dim ppt As Object, ps As Variant, slide As Variant
    
    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
    Set ps = ppt.presentations.Add
    Set slide = ps.slides.Add(1, 1)

    Dim Shp As Shape, ShpName
    For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
        With Shp
            ShpName = .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1) & ".png"
            .Copy
        End With
        With slide
            .Shapes.Paste
            .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Export destFolder & ShpName, ppShapeFormatPNG
            .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Delete
        End With
    Next Shp

    With ps
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
    ppt.Quit
    Set ppt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Coupla notes: " Dim ppt As Object, ps As Variant, slide As Variant" ... ps and slide should be dimmed as Objects. This way they're variants containing objects. Might as well do it the simple way.  "Dim Shp As Shape, ShpName" ShpName is now a Variant. Instead, Dim ShpName as String. Nitpicky, yes. But VB can bite you if you're not careful with this stuff.

Comment: I was playing around with the script but I need more help :(

Images are embedded as 9% of original size to cell. Current script works well when saving 9% image size. 

But I need original size. Tried changed image size to 100% before running script, scripts saves sometimes 18 images, sometimes 24, sometimes 56, very unstable.